# Add event to checkbox[] in wordpress plugin contact form 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, checkbox

I want to add a `change`, `click` or any other event to detect when checkbox change to show a hidden field. I achieved to reproduce [this demo](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-this-is-how-to-showhide-fields-with-jquery) and it's working using a dropbox, now I want to customize with a checkbox.

If I use an `accept` checkbox it works like a charm in this way:

```
[acceptance name id:name]
```

Creates

```
<input type="checkbox" id="name" value="Value">
```

Then

```
$('#name').change(function() {
    if ($("#name")[0].checked == true) {
```

But as long as checkbox creates an array even with one option:

```
[checkbox name id:name "Value"]
```

Creates

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="Value">
```

When I do same does not work. I can find `checked` value using this ugly path:

```
$("#name")[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].checked
```

But `change`, `click` or other events are not present to set up...

How can I access to event in the checkbox to show hidden field when checked?

Comment: if the id is added then use event delegation use `$(document).on('change','#name',function() {`

Comment: How about `$('[name="name[]"]').on('EVENT',HANDLER)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are selecting elements considering array like `name` attributes or just `name attributes`, Use [`attribute selector(jQuery( "[attribute='value']" ))`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

For example, `$('[name="name[]"]').on('EVENT',HANDLER)`